# Banno Permissions for Third-Party Push Notifications

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Our mutual customer submitted this question to Banno via support case:

> We are working with Agent IQ to integrate their chat service into Banno. As part of their chat service, they are trying to configure push notifications. Push notifications generate when a customer receives a chat message from an agent (i.e. teller).
>
> Please provide details on push notification capabilities.  Agent IQ's goal is for a generic notification, to a specific customer, to notify the customer that they have a message to view in their chat. How do we configure Banno People, so that Agent IQ can send push notifications?

This is the response that they received from Banno support:

> Your best bet would be to sign up for this tool kit meetup here:
>
> https://www.jackhenry.com/meetup/toolkit-meetup-may-2023
>
> because what you are referring to - would give access to messages - create a message that goes to everyone - which is not what you are wanting. This sounds like it would require custom integration - so I would try stack overflow again - or that toolkit meetup.
>
> Please let me know if you have questions - thanks so much! Molly

Can you please answer our mutual customer's question? To date, they have not received confirmation from Banno that the **Manage Institution Messages** permission is the permission that will allow us (third party) to generate push notifications within Banno. If a call is easier to facilitate resolution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs for the [Alerts endpoint](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/alerts/details/) in the *Admin API*:

> Requires the "Manage institution messages" permission

[image]

That means your [Associated User](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/overview/authentication/associateduser/) needs to have that permission to use that endpoint.